# Get value of field in view with formBuilder angular2

Tags: forms, angular

I have this field :

```
<form (ngSubmit)="postComment()" [formGroup]="commentForm">

<textarea formControlName="comment"></textarea>

...
```

I want show value in div :

```
<div>{{commentForm.controls.comment.???}}</div>
```

Comment: try `<div>{{ commentForm.get('comment').value }}</div>`

Comment: Yes, it works thanks !

Comment: @ranakrunal9, please post a proper answer so this question can be resolved. Someone else tried and was chastised for it because of your comment-answer.

Answer (score 5):

To get value on control, first we have to get control with **get** method and then have to fetch **value** property as below :

```
<div>{{ commentForm.get('comment').value }}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I use for Angular 12:

```
<div>{{ commentForm.controls['comment'].value }}</div>
```

or

```
<div>{{ commentForm.get('comment')?.value }}</div>
```